# why I got linter error after pull request to person repository?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a repository that I have forked in GitHub.

Then, I want to pull request in GitHub, and after I've pulled request, I got this problem, I don't know what's the solution from that.

But I've rechecked again from my repo there's no typo in my repositories. What should I do? Is there a solution from that?

[image: Linter error message]

Comment: The repo you forked has a lint checker attached to it, and is requesting for an Alphabetical order correction on the indicated file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the original repository has a [workflow action like Pull-Request linter](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pull-request-linter), which would allow the maintainer to setup a liner.

> By default, a workflow only runs when a pull_request's activity type is opened, synchronize, or reopened.
> [Possible values](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull-request-event-pull_request):
>
> ```
> types: [opened, edited, reopened]
> ```